# Use existing ssh keypair in juju

Tags: ssh, juju

How can I use an existing ssh keypair with juju? When running `juju bootstrap` I'm getting this error: `error: environment has no access-key or secret-key`.

I've already setup an ssh keypair a long time ago to use with git. So when I run `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` i'm being asked if I want to overwrite it. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is not about an SSH Key pair but for the cloud providers Access Key and Secret key. If you're using Amazon you'll need to enter your Amazon AWS access and secret key in to your `~/.juju/environments.yaml` file. Check the [juju website](http://juju.ubuntu.com/get-started) for more information, and in particular the [Juju EC2 Provider Getting Started](https://juju.ubuntu.com/get-started/amazon/) guide if you are indeed using AWS/EC2